# Find all metric space or topological space with this property for all $A,B \subset X$ we have $\overline{A \cap B} =\overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Find all metric space or topological space with this property for all $A,B \subset X$ we have $\overline{A \cap B} =\overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$. For finite $X$ this is true. so for discrete topology this is true . Is for infinite $X$ answer discrete topology ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If the space is not discrete, then there as a set $A$ such that $\overline A\setminus A\neq\emptyset$. Take $b\in\overline A\setminus A$ and let $B=\{b\}$.